# How to implement simple Signal/Slot mechanism in C/C++ without using any libraries?

Tags: c++, callback, signals, signals-slots, type-safety

I'm new to GUI programming like gtkmm. I'm struggling with libsigc++ but I don't know

- What is the meaning of Signal/Slot?
- How can we create that without using sigc and Qt in C/C++?
- And What is the meaning of type-safe callback?

Comment: Why the requirement of not using *any* library? While I understand you may not want to use Qt, Boost should not be a big problem. Check out Boost.Signals2

Comment: Because I want to learn the concept of signals. I'm reading libsigc++, but I'm confused.

Comment: If you want to learn the *concept*, then using a library (like Boost.Signals2) and reading through its documentation is the best thing you can do. If you want to understand how it works, that's another story. But I would strongly suggest you not to delve into the implementation details before having understood the concept itself.

Comment: Thanks Andy, I have learned the basic concepts from library documentations.